# Python pexpect scripts run without error,but there are no outputs in output file

Tags: python, linux, devops, pexpect

I want to put the results of 'ls /home' into mylog1.txt through ssh.So,I can check it on my computer.When I run the script,there is no error,there is no output in mylog1.txt。

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import pexpect
> import sys
>
> child=pexpect.spawn('ssh shiyanlou@192.168.42.2')
> fout=file('mylog1.txt','w')
> child.logfile=fout
>
> child.expect("password:")
> child.sendline("xxxxx")
> child.expect('$')
> child.sendline('ls /home')
> ```

```
shiyanlou:pythontest/ $ cat mylog1.txt                                                                                    
shiyanlou@192.168.42.2's password: xxxxxxx 
ls /home
```

There are just tow commands in the mylog1.txt file.Why?

Comment: Thanks a lot! @whjm.I have change my code.At the last line,append child.expect(pexpect.EOF),it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait until the `ls` command finishes, just like when you are interacting with the terminal. See following example (I'm using public key auth for ssh so no password prompt):

```
[STEP 106] # cat foo.py
import pexpect

shell_prompt = 'bash-[.0-9]+[$#] '

ssh = pexpect.spawn('ssh -t 127.0.0.1 bash --noprofile --norc')
ofile = file('file.out', 'w')
ssh.logfile_read = ofile

ssh.expect(shell_prompt)

ssh.sendline('echo hello world')
ssh.expect(shell_prompt)

ssh.sendline('exit')
ssh.expect(pexpect.EOF)
[STEP 107] # python foo.py
[STEP 108] # cat file.out
bash-4.3# echo hello world
hello world
bash-4.3# exit
exit
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
[STEP 109] #
```

Answer (score 0):

pexpect is good to intereact with an application.

But if you simply want ssh and execute some command, i will advice you to try out [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/)